# Flat file parsing : when some fields contain the delimiter

Tags: java, parsing, spring-batch, flat-file

I have a spring-batch application that reads a file with this reader :

```
<bean id="tradeItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
            <constructor-arg value="${input.file.path}/#{jobExecutionContext['trades']}" type="java.lang.String"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <!-- split it -->
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <beans:property name="strict" value="false" />
                    <beans:property name="includedFields" value="0,2,3,6" />
                    <property name="names"
                        value="field0,field2,field3,field6" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="trade" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The fields are delimited by a comma `,`, and here is the catch : some fields look like `[LON, TGT]` and the line ends up wrongly parsed, because of the comma inside the square brackets.

Example :

Input : `Global,,VERIFIED,[LON, TGT],ERerd,3456585,QTR,20190929,20231020`

Desired output : `Global`, `VERIFIED`, `[LON, TGT]`, `QTR`

Actual output : `Global`, `VERIFIED`, `[LON`, `3456585`

How can I achieve that ? I don't have control over the input file.

***EDIT***

This is not a duplicate, as the proposed solution would not work : here we don't have a single quote-character, but we have 2 different ones, the opening bracket and the closing bracket.

Comment: What kind of file is it ? Is it a text file with comma delimited ?

Comment: Yes it's a comma delimited csv file

Comment: Ok, Check OpenCSV framework to parse the CSV file.

Comment: Do you have control over which character is used as a delimiter in your source file?

Comment: @All - I would suggest change file like `Global, VERIFIED, LON, TGT, QTR`, based on the indexed position 2 and 3, you can pick up data and do the needful. This way you can have correct CSV file

Comment: @Luca Basso Ricci, Stephen C : the answer provided in the link won't work, here I have 2 different quote characters.

Comment: Your CSV is invalid because `[LON, TGT]` must be quoted. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules about how to quote fields with separator inside

Comment: Fine, but as I said, I have no control over the way this file is generated, and I still have to deal with it. I ended up writing a custom delimited line tokenizer.

Comment: Ok. I'll reopen the question so you can post the solution for other people!

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Luca Basso Ricci, my input csv is invalid, but I still have to deal with it because I have no control over it.

So I wrote my own delimited line tokenizer, which is just the `DelimitedLineTokenizer` with a rewritten `isDelimiter()` method, and replaced it in the conf file :

```
  private boolean isDelimiter(char[] chars, int i, String token, int endIndexLastDelimiter) {
    boolean result = false;
    
    int openingBrackets = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, 0, i)),  "[");
    int closingBrackets = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, 0, i)),  "]");
    
    boolean inBrackets = (openingBrackets - closingBrackets > 0);
    
    if ((i - endIndexLastDelimiter >= this.delimiter.length()) && 
      (i >= token.length() - 1)) {
      String end = new String(chars, i - token.length() + 1, token.length());
      if (token.equals(end)) {
        result = !inBrackets;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```